# Add "COD-BO3" synonym for call of duty black ops 3?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

A lot of people refer to *Call of Duty Black Ops 3* as "COD BO3" to shorten it to 7 characters.

Can we get [cod-bo3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cod-bo3) as a synonym for [call-of-duty-black-ops-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/call-of-duty-black-ops-3)?

Comment: It's been done. YAY!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is worth doing. There's certainly no *harm* in adding a synonym - it's not going to change the current use of the tag. In fact, synonyms are *meant* for [**common, alternate spellings or phrasings**](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags/call-of-duty-black-ops-3/synonyms) for tags, so that people can find them easier when writing questions or searching tags.

In fact, the Call of Duty series has a long history of being shortened in the way you're suggesting by the CoD community, and Google recognises them and gives similar results on searches.

So given that, I have created the synonym [cod-bo3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cod-bo3) -> [call-of-duty-black-ops-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/call-of-duty-black-ops-3) for you.

Answer (score -6):

I don't see the need for this at all.  You can refer to the game with the shortened terminology in the question, but a shorter tag doesn't help searchability at all.

Comment: It makes people NOT have to remember the whole tag, + you can be lazy.